# How to display items in Admin view with Vuex and Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating e-shop and I want to store my available products and being able to edit/remove them from my Admin view. However It is just not displaying any of the available products, when Im logged in to the Admin view.

Here is my VueX:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { dbMenuAdd } from '../../firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cart: [],
    avaibleProducts: [],
    currentUser: null
  },
  getters: {
    countOfCartProducts: state => {
      return state.cart.length
    },
    myCart: state => {
      return state.cart
    },
    getTotal: state => {
      return state.cart.reduce((total, lineItem) => Number(total) + Number(lineItem.price), 0);
    },
    currentUser: state => {
      return state.currentUser
    },
    getAvaibleProducts: state => {
      return state.avaibleProducts
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_TO_CART: (state, product) => {
      if (state.cart.findIndex(item => item.id === product.id) !== -1) {
        return
      }
      else {
        state.cart.push(product)
      }
    },
    REMOVE_FROM_CART: (state, product) => {
      state.cart.splice(product, 1)
    },
    userStatus(state, user) {
      if (user) {
        state.currentUser = user
      } else {
        state.currentUser = null
      }
    },
    setAvaibleProducts: state => {
      let avaibleProducts = []

      dbMenuAdd.onSnapshot((snapshotItems) => {
        avaibleProducts = []
        snapshotItems.forEach((doc) => {
          var avaibleItemData = doc.data();
          avaibleProducts.push({
            ...avaibleItemData,
            id: doc.id
          })
        })
      })
      state.avaibleProducts = avaibleProducts
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setUser(context, user) {
      context.commit('userStatus', user)
    },
    setAvaibleProducts: context => {
      context.commit('setAvaibleProducts')
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
});
```

Here is my Admin.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <main>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="btn-container">
        <router-link to="/addNew">
          <button class="add-to-cart">
            ADD NEW ITEM
          </button></router-link
        >
      </div>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div id="avaible">
          <div
            class="p-avaible"
            v-for="item in avaibleProducts"
            :key="item.name"
          >
            <router-link
              @click.native="scrollToTop"
              :to="{ name: 'Product', params: { ...item } }"
            >
              <img :key="item.image" :src="item.image" />
            </router-link>
            <div class="p-name">{{ item.name }}</div>
            <div class="p-price">€{{ item.price }}</div>
            <div class="btn-container">
              <button class="remove" @click="deleteProduct(item.id)">
                REMOVE
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import { dbMenuAdd } from "../../firebase";

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["ADD_TO_CART"]),
    addToCart(item) {
      this.ADD_TO_CART(item);
    },
    deleteProduct(id) {
      dbMenuAdd
        .doc(id)
        .delete()
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Document sucessfully deleted!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cart: [],
      computed: {
        showProduct() {
          const id = this.$route.params.id;
          const product = this.avaibleProducts.find((p) => p.uuid == id);
          return product;
        },
        avaibleProducts() {
          return this.$store.getters.getAvaibleProducts;
        },
      },
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    return this.$store.dispatch("setAvaibleProducts");
  },
};
</script>

<style type="scss" scoped>
.edit {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.remove {
  color: white;
  background-color: crimson;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Does anyone know why no products are displayed?
Am I calling the getter wrong?
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you debug with https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools to see if the products are in the store? Also, how do you declare `dbMenuAdd`?

Comment: Its working. Its showing me the avaibleProducts array in Vue Debugger, however its empty.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "however it's empty"? Is the `avaibleProducts` array empty **in the store (vuex)**? or empty in the component?

Comment: Yes after logging and going to admin page where i remove and add items. The existing ones in database are not existing in the array that is looped in the Admin.vue .